# Is there a word for: a new version of a piece of literature

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I seen a TV show that was reinvented as a graphic novel.
 
So I wrote: I find this iteration quite disturbing.

I used "iteration" but that applies to a new version of software as I could not find the right word.

Is this an acceptable usage or is there a better word to use?

Comment: ***edition*** is the standard term

Comment: This version of a work of creative thing. Version of a work.

Comment: For what it's worth, *iteration* can apply to anything that's part of a recurring series of events, not just software.

Comment: Why all the close votes? This completely fits in with single-word-requests.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean: it was a TV show, and now it has been re-done as a graphic novel.  I would not call that a *new edition*.  I would call it an *[adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(arts))*:

> An adaptation is a transfer of a work of art from one medium to another.

<sup>Wikipedia</sup>

Comment: +1 "John Smith wrote the original book; Jane Green adapted it for the stage".

Answer (score -1):

a new **edition**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/edition)

> d. A version of an earlier publication having substantial changes or
>   additions: a newly revised edition of a standard reference work.